# Custom Report: List customer's email address for a specific SKU

Tags: magento-1.8, reports

I have a new product arriving in 2 weeks that is very closely related to another I have been successfully selling for 4 months.

I want to be able to get a list of customer's email addresses for a specific SKU in any format that I can then import into Mailchimp.

I will then be able to alert the customers about the new exclusive product that will be a limited run in production.

Answer (score 1):

So to get the customer email in sql the following should be enough.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_email FROM sales_flat_order_item i
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON o.entity_id = i.order_id
WHERE o.customer_id IS NOT NULL
AND i.sku = "product-sku"
```